# Is there a way to make the login screen in ubuntu need ctrl-alt-del to put in your info?

Tags: authentication, passwords, linux, ubuntu

In Windows, there is an option for a logon screen that looks like this:

[Image](https://www.google.com/url?sa=i&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=images&cd=&ved=0ahUKEwirkLyfhPfYAhXCzFMKHcfdBoQQjRwIBw&url=https%3A%2F%2Fws-technologies.wonderhowto.com%2Fhow-to%2Fadd-ctrl-alt-delete-windows-7-logon-0132359%2F&psig=AOvVaw2OUWfGp2q0cUfxlgaRxZFK&ust=1517104346613204)

is there a way to do the same thing on Ubuntu?

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/790088/how-do-you-protect-ubuntu-login

Comment: not quite what i need, this is more for when there are multiple users, and I need a page like that windows screen.